# Super introductory geometry textbook recommendations

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation

So I've recently started taking maths seriously in hopes of doing physics at university and have gotten pretty good at algebra and learned some very basic calculus but I'm having trouble finding a good introductory geometry textbook. I know this question has already been asked at least twice before and I looked at the at some of the recommendations, but I feel they're geared toward more undergraduate study as I'm assuming the guys who asked the questions already did high school geometry which isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for comprehensive high school equivalent introductory geometry textbook that's fairly challenging and would set me up for learning more in depth topics that crop up in physics later. (I say fairly challenging because, like I said, I feel like I'm pretty good at algebra).

Consider me somebody who has never done geometry before because that's basically what I am.

Thanks.

(PS. I've never asked for book recommendations before so forgive me if I'm being too vague, I'll gladly amend my request if anyone needs clarification)

Comment: Did you try Amazon? Search for high school geometry or middle school geometry and look at the ones with the highest ratings. When you see one you like, you can either buy it there, buy it from somewhere else or see if you can find a .pdf online. This really applies to most subjects.

Comment: Additionally, have you considered a youtube playlist? Imo most of the time those are more helpful than books when self learning.

Comment: "The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Geometry" by D. Wells might be an introductory pleasant book where to begin. Then switch to "Geometry: A High School Course" 
by Serge Lang and Gene Murrow.